# Can there be more than one alt attribute on an image?

Tags: html, css, alt

This is kind of a simple question but is there a way I can have more than on alt on an img.
If there is it would look like this maybe:

`<img src="happy.jpeg" alt="happy face" alt="Smiley Face">`

or

`<img src="happy.jpeg" alt="'happy face', 'Smiley Face'">`

Comment: why you need two alts?

Comment: You can only have one alt. What you choose to have in that alt is up to you, it is a string. Be careful what you put there, a user with a screen reader is going to hear all of the alt text. It seems as you are trying to do some filtering? If so there are better ways to do it like using data-attributes.

Comment: @Bouh one to identify the image and one to make the image be seen when you search it

Comment: @ Dejan.S what are data atributes?

Comment: Alt tags are meant to containt keywords. Also, Alt tags should contain enough information for people who can 't see the images to understand what the image represents. So I think this should to the trick :

`<img src="happy.jpeg" alt="happy smiley face">
`

Comment: @CharfiOmar I know what alt tags are, I was just wondering if you could have 2, 

I would try it but I don't know how to test it

Comment: it's not valid, you can test it from https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea

Comment: @Bouh what do you mean its not valid

Comment: Can you explain a bit more how you think regarding this, "identify the image" and "make the image be seen when you search it"?

Comment: @Dejan.S one alt attribute will be for text to speech purposes, or if the image doesn't load, the other will be so search engines can find it when people search the second alt I put on it

Comment: There was the longdesc attribute you could use aside, but, nowdays, data-attributes allow you to create extra attributes. you may do something alike : `<img src="img.png" alt="Happy Face" data-alt="Smiley Face" data-alt-2="Green Face" >` It will be valid. See https://css-tricks.com/a-complete-guide-to-data-attributes/

Comment: I wouldn't put too much into that. Search engines are way smarter then just looking at your alt text to decide what it is.

Comment: for search engine, I would give a name to that img file that describes it

Comment: yeah ok thanks guys for all your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here in [HTML Specs](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#attributes-2) says that:

> There must never be two or more attributes on the same start tag whose
> names are an ASCII case-insensitive match for each other.

It actually ignores the second attribute with the same name and only uses the first one.

Also when you specify an attribute using double-quoted attribute value syntax like this,

```
<img src="happy.jpeg" alt="'happy face', 'Smiley Face'">
```

you only pass this single string, not multiple keywords:

`'happy face', 'Smiley Face'`

Comment: Thank you for this but I don't uderstand the quote, can you explain it to me?

Comment: Meaning when you use two alt attributes on the same <img> tag, it causes a parsing error and parser doesn't evaluate the second alt attribute. It just uses the first one.

Comment: @MartMayda ok that cleared it up mostly but I am relatively new to coding so what is a parsing error

Comment: When you write an HTML document and open it up in a browser, parser engine (which is already built in the browser) interprets the document you wrote and renders it to the DOM as nodes. If you use incorrect syntax, it throws an internal error but usually all modern browsers handle that error successfully and don't cause you any problems. Just keep an eye on references like MDN web docs or W3Schools when you are writing code and you should be okay. I hope that helps!